# Rename files using php - filenames in text file

Tags: php, rename

I have a list of file names in a text file and i have been reading the text file and using the vales to rename files in the folder. Example of the names in the text file, each name in the file represents two images (front and back).

12455
124788
12145

Basically we have duplex scanned a number of images, scanner gives it a default name of 1, 2, 3 etc and we would like to rename it to the code on the file, so the codes are entered in the text file and the rename program will rename the files accordingly

Problem i am getting is it is only renaming the last two images in the folder. Here is the code thanks for the help

```
<?php
$second_file = "n";
$do_second = "n";
$i = 0;
$count = 0;
if ($handle = opendir('C:\xampp\htdocs\test')) {
$a = 0;
echo "Directory handle: $handle\n";
echo "Files:\n";

$file = fopen("num.txt","r") or exit ("Unable to open file num.txt");
while (!feof($file)){
    $data = fgets($file);
    $data2 = substr($data,0,9);
    $num[$i] = $data2;
    $i = $i + 1;
    $count = $count + 1;
}
$a = 0;
while (false !== ($file2 = readdir($handle))) {
$filename[$a] = $file2;
$a = $a + 1;}
sort($filename,SORT_NUMERIC);
$count2 = 0;
for($a=2; $a <sizeof($filename); $a++){
$value = $num[$count2];
$test = $filename[$a];
$temp2 = substr($filename[$a],0,1);
    if ($temp2 !== "."){
        if ($second_file =="n") {
            $temp = substr($filename[$a], 0, 1);
            if($temp !== "R") {
                        rename("/xampp/htdocs/test/$test","/xampp/htdocs/test/R1 - $value - front.JPG");
                $second_file = "y";
                $do_second = "n";
                print "First file no: $value <br>";
                                  }
                                }
        if ($second_file =="y") {
            $temp = substr($filename[$a], 0, 1);
            if($temp !== "R") {
             if($do_second =="y"){
                rename("/xampp/htdocs/test/$test","/xampp/htdocs/test/R1 - $value - back.JPG");
                $second_file = "n";
                $count2 = $count2 + 1;
                print "Second file yes: $value <br>";
                }
             if($do_second =="n"){
             $do_second = "y";
             }
                              }
                                }                   
                       }

                                          }                                           
fclose($file);  
closedir($handle);
print "Rename complete"; }
```

I keep getting warnings but nothing is being renamed

> Directory handle: Resource id #3 Files: 
>   Warning: rename(/xampp/htdocs/test/1.JPG,/xampp/htdocs/test/R1 - 00650 - front.JPG) [function.rename]: No error in C:\xampp\htdocs\change_name.php on line 33
>   First file no: 00650
>
> Warning: rename(/xampp/htdocs/test/2.JPG,/xampp/htdocs/test/R1 - 00650 - back.JPG) [function.rename]: No error in C:\xampp\htdocs\change_name.php on line 43
>   Second file yes: 00650

Comment: Your algorithm looks very .. complicated. There is a `readdir` in there, I was not expecting to see that. Why do you need it?

Comment: http://tools.arantius.com/tabifier

Comment: Thanks for the quick response, i was using it to obtain the filenames in the current directory. What i found is that there were some hidden files in the directory like . and .. and ...  so i found the first valid filename "1.jpg" then referenced the text file to obtain the first line in the text file to use to rename the file

Comment: i was able to fix it, the problem was $data2 = substr($data,0,9); the names of the files were not 9 characters long so when i trimmed it it worked, thanks